# copy a set of mongo documents from one db docker container and into another

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoimport

i have two docker containers running, like

```
khine@zapotec ~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS          NAMES
4d60202f8da1        mongo:3.2     "docker-entrypoint.sh"   3 months ago        Up 3 months              27017/tcp      mongo-web
52a8569562c8        mongo:2.4     "/entrypoint.sh mongo"   15 months ago       Up 14 months             27017/tcp      mongo-dev                             mongo-dev
```

i can export the users with:

```
docker exec -i mongo-dev sh -c "mongoexport -d ccc-mongo -c users -q '{\"group\" : \"guest\"}'" > guest_users.js
```

but how do i pipe this into the mongo-web container?

```
docker exec -i mongo-web sh -c "mongoimport -d ccc-mongo -c users --file"  < guest_users.js
```

any advice is much appreciated